# I can't get the company logo in the top left (next to Netsuite logo) to change

Tags: netsuite

No matter how small of an image I upload and no matter what file type I use, I cannot get the company logo to change in the top left. Even when I overwrite the file that is currently in use it stays the old logo. I assumed it was finicky about size but it does it no matter how small I make it.

Are there any secrets about the requirements for company logos that are not made evident?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: I tried this myself and it wasn't until I switched roles that the new logo appeared. Give that a try. (Even logging out and in didn't help.)

Comment: Read the help for "Uploading Your Logo" - under 10k, max of 114 x 30 pixels etc.